# Regex for changing certain pattern in XML file

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I need to change the following text

```
<item id="108-109" name="flowers"/>
```

To this

```
<item fromid="108" toid="109" name="flowers"/>
```

On a file with multiple ocurrences of this 'id="num-num"' pattern. Name and the tag itselt doesn't matter.
I've tried lots of different combinations of regex patterns and I can't find one which even finds something. This:

```
id="([0-9])-([0-9])"
```

Which in my mind should work is not working.

I'm using Notepad++ regex finder and testing with RegexPal, but after a lot of tries I'm out of ideas.

Comment: try `id="([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)"`

Comment: Oh hell. I don't know where my mind was to forget the +. Thank you!

Comment: happens to the best of us :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't think it's related...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

search: `id\s*=\s*["'](\d+)-(\d+)["']`
replace: `fromid="$1" toid="$2"`

since your comment, you can simply use:

search: `id="(\d+)-(\d+)"`

Comment: Oh this is a very complex one. I see you also prevented tags like "id = "108-109"". That doesn't happen certainly, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
id="(\d+)-(\d+)"
```